# Programmatically set active user information to Fabric analytics reports

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I want to enrich my app analytic reports by setting analytic user properties to describe segments of my user base. However, I cannot find the way to do it with [Fabric SDK](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/answers-events.html).

With *Firebase*, I used to do it easily using the [setUserProperty](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/properties) API.

Any idea what is the similar API to do so using **Fabric**?

Comment: Don't see any evidence that Fabric Answers supports this directly, based on [the documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/answers-events.html). You could always set up custom events/attributes, abstracted if you want so you can always insert global properties into each call. In my experience the Fabric analytics product is pretty limited.

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. This functionality does not exist within Answers for Analytics. You would want to use Firebase for this.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this Mike